# Mask of boolean 2D numpy array with True values for elements contained in another 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take the following example. I have an array `test` and want to get a boolean mask with True's for all elements that are equal to elements of `ref`.

```py
import numpy as np
test = np.array([[2, 3, 1, 0], [5, 4, 2, 3], [6, 7, 5 ,4]])
ref = np.array([3, 4, 5])
```

I am looking for something equivalent to

```py
mask = (test == ref[0]) | (test == ref[1]) | (test == ref[2])
```

which in this case should yield

```py
>>> print(mask)
[[False,  True, False, False],
 [ True,  True, False,  True],
 [False, False,  True,  True]]
```

but without having to resort to any loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy comes with a function isin that does exactly this

```py
np.isin(test, ref)
```

which return

```py
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: `np.in1d` (used by `isin`) does a repeated `mask |= (ar1 == a)` if `ref` is small enough compared to `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting:

```
mask = (test[:,None] == ref[:,None]).any(1)
```

output:

```
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

*NB. this is faster that `numpy.isin`, but creates a (X, X, Y) sized intermediate array where X, Y is the shape of test, so this will consume some memory on very large arrays*